# How to Dragging and dropping HTML table row to another position(In Jsp) and save the new position (values) also in database(MySql)?

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, struts2

Hi all: I met a problem like this. Here is the scenario: if I have a database table A, which contains several columns, for example. Once the sever pass the database to web client, it's rendered into a HTML table. Now, here is some requirements for the client side. The user will be able to add/delete several rows from the HTML table, in addition, they will also be able the change the row order. If we could finish the client side with the help from some jquery plugin (for example: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/). Now, my question is, how could I pass this information back to server? Because there are new rows and deleted rows, the original table row order (like the plugin tableDnD.serialize function is not sufficient) is not enough.
How to do this?Please let me know if anyone have idea about that.I got stuck in it since 5 days.Thanking you in advance.

on drop row this javascript function is calling.

```
    this.onDrop = function(table, droppedRow) {
   // alert("ondrop1");
   var rows = this.table.tBodies[0].rows;
   var debugStr = "rows now: ";
   for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
       debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
   //  alert(debugStr);
   }
```

//  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'dropped
'+debugStr;
   }

now i have to send new position of row to server side.How to do this?

Comment: Which part of your task are you having problems with right now? Focus on that part and ask a question related to it. Also, please post relevant code or analysis showing what you have accomplished so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i think its better to use jquery ui to drag and drop purposes, they are very handy you can get details from [this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

i cant implement it right now but i think  try using thse codes from thier site may give you some idea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var table = document.getElementById('table-1');
  var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
  tableDnD.init(table);
</script>
```

try to use some alert in side this function may be more helpfull

```
tableDnD.onDrop = function(table, row) {
    var rows = this.table.tBodies[0].rows;
    var debugStr = "rows now: ";
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
    }

    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'row['+row.id+'] dropped<br>'+debugStr;
}
```

if you got the desired data from this  writa an ajax operation in a function and call it from this function or call it on a buttons  click event to save data

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) is a link to ajax tutorial of w3 schools have a refrence,

suppose your function is ajaxcall() then

```
function ajaxcall(readedValue)  { 
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  { 
            var returnreslut=xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(returnreslut==true){
                alert("Sucess");           
            } else  {
                alert("failed");
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","insertQueryPage.jsp",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("value="+readedValue);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I am getting problem in drag and dorp of table row and how to save new position in database also.

Comment: please give more details what r u using for drag and drop is its the same jquery ui plugin and what was the error you got , I think you have to store the position to somewhere like hidden filed and use it to store in databse may be ajax will be more usefull

Comment: For dragging and dropping i used this web site(http://www.isocra.com/2007/07/dragging-and-dropping-table-rows-in-javascript/#demo[^]) code.It is working fine but i am unable to store position in database.In this website code the also talk about Ajax but i don't have idea about Ajax. function is like this -          /** This function is called when you drop a row, so redefine it in your code
        to do whatever you want, for example use Ajax to update the server */
    this.onDrop = function(table, droppedRow) {
        
        // Do nothing for now
    }   but this function is empty .

Comment: Try to do some like yhis in examples given in the site may be you get some idea  <script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById('table-1');
var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
tableDnD.init(table);
</script>      <br/>// Redefine the onDrop so that we can display something
tableDnD.onDrop = function(table, row) {
    var rows = this.table.tBodies[0].rows;
    var debugStr = "rows now: ";
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
    }
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'row['+row.id+'] dropped<br>'+debugStr;
}

Comment: Thank you for answer - now i am able to get row id but how to sent it to java code so that i can update it in DB .

Comment: if you get all the required data then use ajax to store the value to db, hows you keep the data you retrieved is it in any text box or you want to send it directly to insert to db from the function

Comment: here i am getting problem .how to send the data on server side ? as i don,t know ajax please help me.Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Hi I have edited the answer ,added a js function you can call that funtion whenever you wanted a nd pass values to the function as param, I think you you need to have a look on ajax Hopes this will helps You :)

Comment: Thnx for your response .I got the solution by AJAX.